# CASE in WHERE, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I'm doing some search, where users are choosing in dropdown some clauses. When they leave some box empty, I want query to ignore clause. I know CASE, and best I thought of is that if I pass 0 to parameter in stored procedure, it ignores that parameter, like this.

```
WHERE a.Country = (CASE WHEN @Country > 0 THEN @Country ELSE (something else) END)
```

so, (something else) should be like no condition, it can be '>0' as country ids are from all >1, but I don't know how to use > and = in same CASE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A few ways:

```
-- Do the comparison, OR'd with a check on the @Country=0 case
WHERE (a.Country = @Country OR @Country = 0)

-- compare the Country field to itself
WHERE a.Country = CASE WHEN @Country > 0 THEN @Country ELSE a.Country END
```

Or, use a dynamically generated statement and only add in the Country condition if appropriate. This should be most efficient in the sense that you only execute a query with the conditions that actually need to apply and can result in a better execution plan if supporting indices are in place. You would need to use parameterised SQL to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify to:

```
WHERE a.Country = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Country,0), a.Country);
```

Answer (score 3):

`(something else)` should be `a.Country`

if `Country` is nullable then make`(something else)` be `a.Country OR a.Country is NULL`

Comment: Assumes `Country` is not nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WHERE a.Country = (CASE WHEN @Country > 0 THEN @Country ELSE a.Country END)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.. ELSE a.Country ...
```

I suppose