# SQL Server : Where clause inside IF .. ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Like the title already explained, I'm struggling with my `WHERE` clause in my SQL stored procedure.

I got a `SELECT` query which joins multiple tables well and at the end if got a `WHERE` clause that give specific values to search for.

My problem is that I want to expand this stored procedure for 2 different `WHERE` clauses, but I can't get my `IF ELSE` correct to parse the query..

For example:

```
SELECT ....... 
FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....
WHERE 
    man.Klant_ID = @Klant
    AND (@ManID = 0 OR man.ID = @ManID)
    AND .... (which continues like the rule above)
```

Here I want to get something like this:

```
SELECT ....... 
FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....

IF @TEMPVAR = ''
    WHERE man.Klant_ID=@Klant
    AND (@ManID = 0 OR man.ID = @ManID)
    AND... 
ELSE
    WHERE TABLE_X.ID IN (@TEMPVAR)
```

(and `@tempvar` should contain comma separated id's like `10001,10002,10003`)

I'm struggling with the syntax and searched for some while but can't seem to find a right solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this might help  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191424/case-in-where-sql-server

Comment: Quite simply.... you cant do that... You need to put the entire select clause in your IF ELSE..

Comment: When writing SQL, don't think of `IF/ELSE` control structures as mechanisms to _build_ SQL statements. Instead, any logic related to the results returned by the query should be built into its `WHERE` clause and the variables can be used there just as they can in scope of the function or stored procedure.

Comment: Try using a BEGIN and END statement in between your IF statements. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: I updated my question with more information.. My orignal where.. And logic was already like the first given comment here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a CASE:

```
SELECT ....... FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....
WHERE TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 
    CASE WHEN @TEMPVAR = '' THEN 123
         ELSE 456
    END
```

or directly in the `WHERE` clause with an `OR`:

```
WHERE (@TEMPVAR = ''
       AND man.Klant_ID=@Klant
       AND (@ManID = 0 OR man.ID = @ManID)
       AND... 
      ) 
      OR
      (@TEMPVAR <> '' 
       AND TABLE_X.ID IN (@TEMPVAR)
      )
```

Comment: This is indeed a correct solutions for a problem.. But I kinda explained my question wrong.. I've updated my question.. But I appreciate the effort!

Comment: This does indeed separate the clauses perfectly like I wish, so I'm gonna accept your answer! Extra question: the @Tempvar I would like to contain the comma-seperated id's to use, for example:
 .. where ID IN (@TEMPVAR)
(would be WHERE ID IN (10001,10002,10003)) ..

How can I make this possible? Now I declared the TempVar to be 'nvarchar(max)' because it contains commas to..

Comment: That's not simple - you either need to use dynaimc SQL (building a string and appending the comma separated list) or build a function to split the string into a temp table and join to it.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481479/parse-comma-separated-string-to-make-in-list-of-strings-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: Ok, thx a lot for your time! Will look at this solutions to fix me IN-problem aswell!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with directly logic in the `where`:

```
SELECT ....... FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....
WHERE TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 123 and @TEMPVAR = '' or
      TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 456 and @TEMPVAR <> ''
```

If `TEMPVAR` can be `NULL`, then:

```
SELECT ....... FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....
WHERE TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 123 and @TEMPVAR = '' or
      TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 456 and (@TEMPVAR <> '' or @TEMPVAR is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do it is:

```
IF @TEMPVAR = ''
SELECT ....... FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....
WHERE TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 123
    AND ....
ELSE
SELECT ....... FROM TABLE_X
INNER JOIN TABLE_Y.....
WHERE TABLE_X.FIRSTCOLUMN = 456
    AND ....
```