# using if/case in sql server where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a column in where clause in SQL Server 2005, but issue is I have to add it for a given condition like

```
where condition  1
and condition 2
if(@val !=null and @val = 'test')
begin
and condition 3
end
```

but when I try this SQL Server gives me error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'. Severity 15 Procedure Name
Incorrect syntax near 'END'. Severity 15 Procedure Name
```

I did some R&D and found that I should use case statement instead and then I tried this

```
where condition  1
    and condition 2
    CASE @val 
    WHEN 'test' THEN AND condition 3
END
```

but now it's giving error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'. Severity 15 Procedure Name
```

Can any one help me to sort out the problem? Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
select *
from Tables with joins
where ac_jd_date_closed >= convert(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(dd, -@period, getdate()), 101)
and ac_jd_date_closed <= convert(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(dd, 0, getdate()), 101) 
and lo_pc_last_name not in ('Shroder')
and lm_ap_pr_id NOT IN (4743, 2683)
```

I want to add this condition when spm David otherwise this condition should not be there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CASE in WHERE, SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191424/case-in-where-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all to answer the question, but I used a little trick to solve the problem in this way

```
if(@spm='David')
begin

select *
    from Tables with joins
    where ac_jd_date_closed >= convert(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(dd, -@period, getdate()), 101)
    and ac_jd_date_closed <= convert(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(dd, 0, getdate()), 101) 
    and lo_pc_last_name not in ('Shroder')
    and lm_ap_pr_id NOT IN (4743, 2683) 
end  
else 
begin 
select *
    from Tables with joins
    where ac_jd_date_closed >= convert(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(dd, -@period, getdate()), 101)
    and ac_jd_date_closed <= convert(VARCHAR(10),dateadd(dd, 0, getdate()), 101) 
    and lo_pc_last_name not in ('Shroder')
end
```

means i used the same full query with condition, hope this trick will help someone to solve his issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `CASE` statement and substitute `AND (@Val<> 'test' OR (@Val = 'test' AND condition 3))`:

```
WHERE <condition  1>
AND <condition 2>
AND (@Val<> 'test' OR (@Val = 'test' AND <condition 3>))
```

Comment: Note, I've updated this because you need to enclose the whole AND statement in parens.

Answer (score 2):

```
where condition  1
and condition 2
and ((@val='test' and condition 3) Or (@val!='test'))
```

Comment: @roryap you can also use `!=` (in `sql server`, I don't know about other db)

Comment: @roryap: Yes `!=` and `<>` are same

Comment: Just checking.  Didn't know that.

Comment: @roryap i just want to clear one thing from any of you both that in my case condition 3 will not work as a statement, because it is conditional. just clear me if both answers works as per my requirement.

Comment: Why don't you post what is condition3 is

Comment: @zzzz -- I don't understand your question/statement.

Comment: @roryap Plz see the update question with running query

Comment: @zzzz --"see the update question with running query" what are you talking about?  I don't see anything related to my query in your update.

Comment: @roryap Please refresh the page and you will get the updated question