# SQL SERVER - CASE in WHERE (THEN IS NULL ELSE IS NOT NULL )

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have seen this link to find a solution to my problem:

[CASE in WHERE, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191424/case-in-where-sql-server)

However, in my case I need to evaluate that when a parameter has a certain value, it evaluates a field when it **is null or not**, for example:

```
WHERE (CASE @parameter WHEN 1 THEN a.fieldOne IS NULL ELSE a.fieldOne IS NOT NULL END)
```

But this doesn't work for me...

**EDIT 1**

For example when `@parameter = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM
FROM exampleTable as s
WHERE (s.fieldOne IS NULL)
```

And when `@parameter = 0`

```
SELECT * FROM
FROM exampleTable as s
WHERE (s.fieldOne IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Could you explain "doesn't work"? What are you trying to achieve with `ELSE a.fieldOne IS NOT NULL`. A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value.

Comment: What output are you trying to get?    `fieldOne IS NULL` is a conditional test, not an output value.

Comment: Probably duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a `case` expression to return parts of a query like you tried, only values.

However, you could emulate his behavior with logical opertaors:

```
WHERE (@parameter =  1 AND a.fieldOne IS NULL) OR
      (@parameter <> 1 AND a.fieldOne IS NOT NULL)
```